# How to prove mother-child relationship for baby passport if mother's name on birth certificate is different from current legal name?

Tags: usa, passports

My wife's current legal name is SARAH SMITH. On my child's birth certificate, the line for noting the mother says `Mother's Name Prior to First Marriage` which shows her name as DONGMEI HUANG.

My wife changed her name legally to SARAH SMITH during her citizenship naturalization process.

When we apply for our child's passport, how do we prove mother-child relationship?

---

Thanks @Traveller for your comment.

I found USCIS Form N-662 (Petition for Name Change) which shows the old name changing to the new name.

Comment: Presumably the papers relating to the legal name change show her previous name?

Comment: @Traveller that’s the answer I was going to post - post it as such and I will upboat 